# why do divs disappear when using float with %?

Tags: html, css

It seems that when I use float and % for width the other divs disappear

```
 <div id="banner">
 <div id="container">

      <div class="right">
      <div class="topimage"></div>
      <div class="bottomimage"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="bigimage"></div>

 </div>
 </div>
```

css:

```
 #banner {
 margin-top: 30px;
 }

 #container {
 width: 80%;
 margin: auto;
 }

 .right {
 Float: right;
 }

 .topimage {
 background: url(img1.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 width: 20%;
 height: 150px;
 }

 .bottomimage {
 background: url(img2.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 width: 20%;
 height: 150px;
 }

 .bigimage {
 background: url(imgbig.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 width: 80%;
 height: 300px;
 }
```

now this makes the 2 smaller divs disappear, oddly when I set the width of the 3 child divs on pixels it works just fine..

Comment: When you say the other two "disappear", do they just vanish or move somewhere else on the page?

Comment: There isn't some default padding/margin is there? Maybe some 'reset' CSS might aid it...

Comment: Sure, they are 20% of the width of the floating div, but what is the width of the floating div? What is the width of a floating element that has no concrete content? Put some content in the floating div, a line of text for instance, and the two smaller divs will show up.  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hy8HE/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using float, the element takes the width of the content with in it.
And since you dont't have any content, the width is 0px. 
So even 100% of 0px is still 0px.

You should add some width to the "floated div" or add some content in the empty divs.

```
.right {
 float: right;
 width: 50%;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K2cu8/)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the width of the right element:

```
.right {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
}
```

Now, just set the width of the child elements to 100%.

```
.topimage {
  background: url(img1.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}

.bottomimage {
  background: url(img2.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
```